# Launch Console Application and read output asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, console, stdout

I'm trying to launch a game server  (Game: Ark Survival Evolved) via a C# application. (Some kind of wrapper).

This game server is a console application with some output about the current state of the server.
I want to read the output in order to react to it. That's why the reading must happen asynchronously. (I can't wait untill the server has stopped)

My current approach is the following:

```
        public void RunServer()
        {

            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ShooterGameServer").Length <= 0)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                // redirect output stream
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Display(args.Data);


                // set Server.exe path
                p.StartInfo.FileName = path_server;  

                // run server
                p.Start();

                // reading the console
                p.BeginOutputReadLine();
                p.WaitForExit(); // I've tried it without this line but it doesn't really help
            }
        }

        // Show the console output
        void Display(string output)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

The server exe starts perfectly fine, but it stops writing to the console, as soon as the StdOut should appear. (there are some StdErr messages before the StdOut messages which are still shown in the console window).

This is understandable, because I've only  enabled p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true in my code, so the StdErr channel is not affected by it.

The problem is that the redirected Output never shows up in the Display function. It just vanishes into thin air.

If I put a breaking point into the Display function it never gets called untill I close the server.exe. After that it gets called, but the parameter is null.

Unfortunately I don't have any further knowledge about the game server exe.
What am I missing ?

Edit: Turns out that redirecting the output of other exe files (e.g. cmd exe) works just fine. Is there another way I could read the console in my C# application?  Maybe just "copy" the output instead of redirecting it completely?

Comment: Sounds like a buffering problem.